# issue in composer update after pulling a yii project from git

Tags: php, linux, git, yii2, composer-php

I have just cloned and pulled a yii project from yii , I've globally required `fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1` with this command `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"` and also globally required `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` with this command `composer global  require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"` but when i run composer update to make the vender file and autoload to use the project i get the following error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

And I also get the following error when trying to composer update other projects before the update task :

```
The "yiisoft/yii2-composer" plugin requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0, this *WILL* break in the future and it should be fixed ASAP (require ^1.0 for example).
```

can anyone help to fix these two specially the first one , because I suppose the following problems are related .

(I've also tried reinstalling composer but still got the same errors )

Comment: remove fxp `composer global remove "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"` and add last version `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"`. Delete vendor and composer.lock and run composer install.

Comment: @ineersa I've done that but still get the same errors , and also when I run the command to the last version it says nothing to install or update . Really don't know that to do

Comment: Just to inform you, there is an open issue on this at the moment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer/issues/4

Comment: maybe to late but -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009041/yii2-composer-update-fatal-error

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it by

```
composer global remove "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"
```

Then delete `vendor` folder and your `composer.lock` (you will get all of you executions back in next step).

Then run

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"
```

And finally

```
composer install
```

---

If that will not work. Try to delete your global `vendor` folder.
For example, if you are using ubuntu you can find it here `/home/someUser/.composer/vendor` (this will DELETE ALL packages that were installed globally)

Next run `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"`
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between git and composer except how you config git ignore

**did you ignored composer.lock in .gitignore?**

I prefer to not do it, keep composer.lock tracked, this will make all the team working on the same version.

**did you ignored vendor folder?**

I prefer to ignore it, this will reduce size of git pull and push, and no need to push the vendor.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.

maybe you software dependencies have an incompatible version conflict. you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

> The "yiisoft/yii2-composer" plugin requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0,
> this *WILL* break in the future and it should be fixed ASAP (require
> ^1.0 for example).

Try to remove asses plugin then try install it.

```
composer global remove “fxp/composer-asset-plugin”
composer global require “fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1”
```

If this not solve the issue, try to do bellow

1. delete ***vendor*** folder then
2. remove composer.lock
3. run command `composer install`